# К каким типам данных будут автоматически приведены выражения следующего вида (byte * byte) и (short * short)

Tags: java

К каким типам данных будут автоматически приведены выражения следующего вида (byte * byte) и (short * short)

Answer (score 5):

Выражения будут приведены к `int`.
В JLS прописано, что в случае ряда операций (*,/, %, != и др.) c 2 числовыми операндами будет осуществляться [приведение типов с расширением](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

> **5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion**
>   When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
>      conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either
>      or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to
>        double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>        to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>        to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.
>
> After the type conversion, if any, value set conversion (§5.1.13) is applied to each operand.

Таким образом, сперва происходит unboxing, а затем приведение операндов к `int`. Операции, на которые это распространяется:

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators *, / and % (§15.17)
> - The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and - (§15.18.2)
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)
> - The integer bitwise operators &, ^, and | (§15.22.1)
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator ? : (§15.25)

Ну и само приведение типов с расширением:

> **5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion**
>   19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - int to long, float, or double
> - long to float or double
> - float to double

Answer (score 4):

Если я не ошибаюсь, типы данных `byte` и `short` при выполнении операции умножения буду сведены к типу `int`.